# Taking the largest 10 items of a dataset?

Tags: dataset

With a dataset like:

> [image]

How can one take the top 10 items (largest by `FileSize` in this case)?

Comment: `MaximalBy[ds, #FileSize&, 10]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a sample dataset similar to yours:

```
SeedRandom[1]
dataset = Dataset[
    Map[
        <|"FileName"->StringJoin[#, ".PDF"], "FileSize"->Quantity[RandomReal[10^5], "Kilobytes"]|>&,
        RandomWord[100]
    ]
]
```

[image]

Then, you can find the 10 largest files by file size with:

```
dataset[TakeLargestBy[#FileSize&, 10]]
```

[image]

You can also use [`MaximalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy) as in b3m2a1's comment, but in that case it is easier to use the dataset as the first argument of [`MaximalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy) instead of using [`MaximalBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaximalBy) as a query operator.

Comment: You can even use a string to specify the key: `dataset[TakeLargestBy["FileSize", 10]]`

Comment: What does the notation `#FileSize&` signify?